# How can i export a function without passing it as props or using the export keyword?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component like this

```
const ListOfMeds = () => {
  const mockListOfMedicines = [
    {
      medicineName: "Augmentin 625 Duo Tablet",
      medicineId: "D06ID232435454",
      groupName: "Generic Medicine",
      stock: 350,
    },
    {
      medicineName: "Augmentin 625 Duo Tablet",
      medicineId: "D06ID232435454",
      groupName: "Generic Medicine",
      stock: 350,
    },
  ];

  const getSpecificMedicineWithId = (number) => {
    const filteredData = mockListOfMedicines.find((medicine) => {
      return medicine.medicineId === number;
    });

    return filteredData;
  };



 return{
           <Some stuff/> 
       }


};
export default ListOfMeds;
```

i now have another component like this

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const MedicineInfo = () => {
  let params = useParams();

  return <div>MedicineId: {params.medicineId}</div>;
};

export default MedicineInfo;
```

I want the second component to call the function **getSpecificMedicineWithId** in the first component passing in the **params** objects key as the argument. However, the second component is not a child to the first component so I cannot pass that function as a prop. I also cannot use context because of also the same reason. It's not its child.

If I use export on the first component I get the errors

```
Modifiers cannot appear here.
```

and

```
'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level. (58:2)
```

I can't take the **getSpecificMedicineWithId** function out of its component so as to export it because it depends on the data inside the component to work i.e the **mockListOfMedicines** array.

Now I'm stuck I don't know how to go about it. Kindly Help.

Comment: *"I also cannot use context because of also the same reason. It's not its child."* But that's part of what context is for, sharing information not just parent->child but between siblings and cousins.

Comment: That said, if component A needs to call a function created inside component B where A is not a child of B, that seems like a design issue. That really shouldn't be necessary in the vast majority of cases. For instance, here, it seems like both components should be using some kind of data store that is outside both of them. (Perhaps in context, or just in the ancestor they both have in common and passed down, or a Redux store, or...)

Comment: _"because it depends on the data inside the component to work"_: I reckon this is your key problem. If you passed this data down from a parent, or accessed it from context it probably wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if i used context remember i don't have somewhere where I can wrap the components inside a provider.

Comment: @AmohPrince - *Somewhere*, I bet you do. Everything is under the root, right? In the vast majority of cases. But again, I think the real answer is a store both components use.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks it just worked. I've solved the problem by going and wrapping the data in the original main component and it worked. Like the global component. THanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you must declare and export the function outside the component. Because your data is fixed here, you can have the function anywhere you want. (Maybe you should put it in an helper file for more cleanliness.)

```js
// ListOfMeds.jsx
export const getSpecificMedicineWithId = (number) => {
  const mockListOfMedicines = [
    {
      medicineName: "Augmentin 625 Duo Tablet",
      medicineId: "D06ID232435454",
      groupName: "Generic Medicine",
      stock: 350,
    },
    {
      medicineName: "Augmentin 625 Duo Tablet",
      medicineId: "D06ID232435454",
      groupName: "Generic Medicine",
      stock: 350,
    },
  ];

  const filteredData = mockListOfMedicines.find((medicine) => {
    return medicine.medicineId === number;
  });

  return filteredData;
};

const ListOfMeds = () => {
  return <Some stuff /> 
};

export default ListOfMeds;
```

```js
// MedicineInfo.jsx
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

import { getSpecificMedicineWithId } from "./ListOfMeds";

const MedicineInfo = () => {
  let params = useParams();

  const medicine = getSpecificMedicineWithId(parrams.medicineId);

  return <div>MedicineId: {params.medicineId}</div>;
};

export default MedicineInfo;
```

Comment: @LukasLaudrin can i make the function its own component so that I can use useeffect or any other things I want

Comment: You can make it a custom hook. What are the "other things" you want to use ?

Comment: That was a good suggestion. You basically find the data in one common data store